# How to create a dynamic array based on checkbox data-attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

if I click on one checkbox, need to create a dynamic array based on its data-attribute value and push all checked checkbox value with same data-attribute value to this array.

Ex: if i click on height,i need to create an array with its data-attribute value and push all checkbox with checked value in this array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="1" value="1">brand
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="2" value="2">style
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="3" value="3">height
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="4" value="4">width
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="2" value="5">style
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="3" value="6">height
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="3" value="7">height
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.checkbox').click(function(){
            var newarray = [];
            var id = $(this).val();
            var pid = $(this).attr('data-parent');
            newarray[pid] = id;
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: So, this question was already asked, and answered.  Why was it deleted?  The answer is still valid

Comment: @Taplar you are just pushing the attribute value to a array, here i need to create an array for each like if i click height,create one array for height and push all checked height value to this array

Comment: Then you need to include the html associated with what you are trying to do to make it more clear.

Comment: @Taplar updated the question

Comment: So, if one height is checked, you want the array to contain all the values for all the heights, regardless of if they are checked or not?

Comment: @Taplar if i checked height i need to create array with its attribute value(this will be same for all height) and push to this array and like for all

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  "and push to this array and **like for all**"  what does that mean?

Comment: @Taplar First there is an array called "newarray",  if i click "height checkbox",create one array or if i click "style checkbox" create another and push this checkbox value to this array and all created array will come inside this "newarray"

Comment: Except your `newarray` is scoped to your click event handler, so it is destroyed at the end of each method call.  And why are you wanting to create arrays with a single element in them?

Comment: @Taplar then what will be the good solution, i need to pass this filter values to ajax for filtering.. all checked height in an array like this

Comment: Are you wanting to send all the values, not data values, that are checked to the ajax?

Comment: @Taplar yes based on the attribute value,if multiple height is checked then all height checkbox value in an array with index with attribute value of height checkbox

Comment: Check the modified answer to see if that is more along the lines of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var filterCriteria = {};

var $checkboxes = $('.checkbox').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var parentValue = $this.data('parent');
  
  filterCriteria[parentValue] = $checkboxes
    .filter(`[data-parent="${parentValue}"]:checked`)
    .map(function(){ return this.value })
    .get();
    
  console.log( filterCriteria );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="1" value="1">brand
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="2" value="2">style
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="3" value="3">height
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="4" value="4">width
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="2" value="5">style
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="3" value="6">height
<input type="checkbox" name="" class="checkbox" data-parent="3" value="7">height
```

This may be more what you're after.  If you are wanting to group values by their parent key, to know which values to filter on which key.  It filters the checkboxes by the checkbox changed, maps out their values, gets the basic array, and then sets them on the filter object.

Comment: you are just pushing the attribute value to a array, here i need to create an array for each like if i click height,create one array for height and push all checked height value to this array

Comment: if unchecking,how can we remove this value

Comment: It's already removing it.  The parent will still be there, but with an empty array